# ANDROID DIRECTION AND DISTANCE MATRIX API

Tags: android, google-distancematrix-api

I have integrated distance matrix api and direction api of Google Maps.
From Direction api, I get distance and time for 3 routes. If I select a route other than best route and then if I call distance matrix api, then it gives distance & time between two points of best route, where as I want distance and time of selected route.  There is any way to pass route id in distance matrix api or should use any other api to achieve this.

Comment: I'm unfortunately not clear on what you're asking. Can you please give examples of the API calls you're making, the results you get vs the expected results you wish to get instead? Are you talking about waypoints maybe? Note that only Directions API supports waypoints.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for replying, i m getting no of routes from direction api till this things are correct, i m selecting one route out of all routes. currently i m using distance matrix api which is returning me the distance and time of best route only .                                                                                                                            Where as i want distance and time of selected route. which api will provide me to achieve this while travelling